# d3js elements not updated when data is updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to the document, a collection should update itself if the data is updated. For example, I have two elements in an array:

```
[{name: "Tom", age:10}, {name: "Prank", age:12}]
```

and this data is already joined to the following DOM elements

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">Tom is 10 yrs old</div>
  <div class="el">Prank is 12 yrs old</div>
</div>
```

and the data is updated.

```
[{name: "Tom", age:20}, {name: "Prank", age:22}]
```

I want the DOM to be

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="el">Tom is 20 yrs old</div>
  <div class="el">Prank is 22 yrs old</div>
</div>
```

but since the number of elements and the size of data is the same, the div elements do not seem to get updated. Am I missing something here? The above example is a simplified version of my code below, but I believe understanding how to update the above example correctly will solve the problem.

```
  function draw(data) {
    var bars = d3.select(".container")
      .selectAll(".bar-wrapper")
      .data(data);
    var barEnter = bars
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "bar-wrapper")
    barEnter
      .append("button")
      .text(function(d) { return "Vote "+ d.name; })
      .attr("class", "vote-btn btn-default btn-primary")
      .on("click", function(d) {
        console.log("send Data", d.name);
        sendData(d.name);
      });
    barEnter
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("width", function (d) {
        return (d.vote*10) + "px";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.vote });
    bars
      .exit()
      .remove()
  };
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are not handling the update selection -- `bars.text(function(d) { return d.vote });`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Could you elaborate more? I have to change bar's width and label based on the updated data.

Comment: As I've said -- handle the update selection. You'd need to run the code that you run when adding the elements, so to change the width as well, do `.style("width", function (d) {
        return (d.vote*10) + "px";
      })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you so much! I figured it out because of your comment. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? The solution was handling the bars in the update selection like you said. `bars.selectAll("div").text(function ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not handling the update selection, only the enter and exit selections. For the update selection, set the relevant attributes again:

```
bars.style("width", function (d) {
    return (d.vote*10) + "px";
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d.vote });
```